# Can any body help me how to convert this code to swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, alamofire

`Alamofire` change the method for the download request can anybody help me how can I get the `response.suggestedFilename!` in new method?

```
Alamofire.download(.GET, "url", destination:
        {
            (temporaryURL, response) in
        let pathComponent = response.suggestedFilename!
        let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

        let directoryURL = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
        let fileUrl = directoryURL.appendingPathComponent(pathComponent)
        return fileUrl!
    })
```

Comment: Check "temporaryURL" or "destinationURL" properties of response.

Comment: If you have managed conversion to V4 can you post the code please

Answer (score 1):

The DefaultDownloadResponse type is returned when using the new DownloadRequest.response API.

```
Alamofire.download(urlString).response { response in
    debugPrint(response)
    print(response.temporaryURL)
}
```

Check complete [Alamofire 4.0 Migration Guide here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%204.0%20Migration%20Guide.md#response-serializers)